# Why is the inequality sign reversed here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am tasked to find the values of $x$ that satisfy $y<5$ for the equation$$y=\frac{x-2}{x+1}$$

I took the following steps:
$$\frac{x-2}{x+1}<5$$
$$x-2<5x+5$$
$$-4x<7$$
Dividing on both sides by -4 hence changing equality signs yields:
$$x>-\frac{7}{4}$$
And since there is a discontinuity at $x=-1$
$$x<-1$$
However the correct answer given in the textbook is $$-1<x<-\frac{7}{4}$$ Why is this so, have I made an error in my working or is there a lapse in my knowledge?

Comment: That cannot be the correct answer because $\{x \mid -1<x<-\frac{7}{4} \}$ is an empty set.

Comment: @Filthyscrub The answer in your book is wrong. Try $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid cross multiplication in inequations. If you want to do it then make cases:

Case 1: $x+1>0~~~~(1)$ $$\implies (x-2)<5(x+1) \implies -4x <7 \implies x>-7/4~~~(2).$$
The overlap of (1) and (2) is $x>-1.~~~(3)$

Case 2: $x+1<0~~~~(4)$ $$\implies (x-2) >5(x+1) \implies x<-7/4~~~(5)$$
The overlap of (4) and (5) is $x<-7/4~~~(6)$

The final answer is the union of these two cases (3), (6): $x<-7/4$ or $x>-1$, Equivalently $x\in (-\infty, -7/4)\cup (-1, \infty).$

Note: When you multiply an inequation by a negative factor as declared  in Case 2 above,the sign of the inequation changes.

Answer (score 2):

Because $x+1$ may be negative.

The right solution is the following:
$$\frac{x-2}{x+1}<5$$ it's
$$\frac{-4x-7}{x+1}<0,$$ which gives $$x>-1$$ or $$x<-\frac{7}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A variant solution: rewrite the function first
$$\frac{x-2}{x+1}=1-\frac3{x+1},$$
so the inequation can be rewritten as
$\;\dfrac 3{x+1}>-4$.
Two cases:

- either $x>-1$: the l.h.s. is positive, so the inequation is satisfied by any of these $x$;
- or $x<-1$. We have
  $$-4<\frac3{x+1}<0\iff \frac{x+1}3<-\frac14\iff x< -\frac34-1=-\frac74,$$
  so the set of solutions is $\:\bigl(-\infty,-\frac74\bigr)\cup\bigl(-1,+\infty\bigr)$.